# Geometric Group Theory, Meier lemma 11.30 about a two-ended groups $G$

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, geometric-group-theory, cayley-graphs

This is probably a basic algebraic (or even set-theoretic) matter. I am reading "Groups, Graphs and Trees" by J. Meier.

It's about Lemma 11.30 which is left as an exercise to the reader. Before I quote the lemma, I need to quote the following prescription:

> Let $G$ be a finitely generated group with $e(G) = 2$, and let
> $\Gamma$ be a Cayley graph of $G$. There is then a finite subgraph $C$
> such that $\Gamma \setminus C$ has exactly two connected, unbounded
> components. By adding all the finite components of $\Gamma \setminus
>  C$ to $C$, we may assume that $\Gamma \setminus C$ consists of exactly
> two connected components, each of which is unbounded. Choose one of
> these two complements, and let $E \subset G$ consist of those elements
> of $G$ that correspond to the vertices in that component. Notice that
> we may apply elements of $G$ to $E$, forming subsets $$gE = \{g \cdot
>  h \mid h \in E\}.$$ Similarly we can left multiply $E^\complement$: $$gE^\complement
>  = \{g\cdot k \mid k \not\in E\}.$$

Now the lemma:

> **Lemma 11.30.** Let $G$ and $E$ be as above, and let $g \in G$. Then, because $G$ is two-ended, either $E\Delta gE$ is finite or $(E\Delta
>  gE)^\complement$ is finite.

**Note**: $A\Delta B$ denotes the symmetric difference $(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$.

I have issues seeing why the given lemma is true. Now let's take the finitely generated two-ended group $\mathbb{Z}$ with the generating set $\{1\}$ and consider the respective Cayley graph $\operatorname{Cay}(\mathbb{Z},\{1\})$.

Let's take $C = \mathcal{B}(0,2) =\{-2,1,0,1,2\}$ as the finite subgraph, that is the ball centered at the vertex corresponding to $0$ with radius $2$.

Then we get the two unbounded connected components

$$D_+ = \{3,4,5,...\}$$ and $$D_- = \{...-5,-4,-3\}$$

Now take the subset $E \subset D_+$ as $$E = \{5,6,7,8,...\}$$

Let's say i choose any positive integer $g \ge 1$, for example $g=2$, then clearly $2E \subset E$. But then we have $$E\Delta 2E = (E\cup 2E)\setminus (E\cap 2E) = E\setminus gE = \{5,6,7,...\}\setminus \{10,12,14,...\} = \{3,4,11,13,15...\}$$ so obviously $$\vert E\Delta 2E \vert = \infty.$$

However, the complement yields $$(E\Delta 2E)^\complement = (E\setminus 2E)^\complement = D_-\cup \mathcal{B}(0,2) \cup \{5,6,7,8,10,12,...\}$$ which is clearly also infinite

$$\vert (E\Delta 2E)^\complement \vert = \infty$$

So my question is: Why is lemma 11.30 true? What am i doing wrong? I am clearly missing something or doing something fundamentally wrong in my argument.

Comment: The operation in ${\mathbb Z}$ is addition, so $2E = \{7,8,9,10,\ldots\}$ and $E \Delta 2E = \{5,6\}$.

Comment: What is $e(G)$?

Comment: $e(G)$ is the number of ends of $G$.

Comment: @Derek: Next question, what is the end of a group? (And is the world a group, as we know it?)

Comment: ohh i totally missed that, thank you so much @DerekHolt. I was really worried. You were incredibly helpful, thanks so much!

Comment: @AsafKaragila the ends of a graph denotes the number of unconnected unbounded components in the complement $\Gamma \setminus C$ of a graph $\Gamma$ where $C$ denotes a finite subgraph. Since the definition does not depend on the chosen set of generators, we call it "ends of a group". Meier explains this quite well.

Comment: Stallings proved that all groups have 0, 1, 2, or $\infty$ ends. Finite groups have zero ends and virtually infinite cyclic groups have two. "Most" other groups have one end, but some, such as nonabelian free groups and (perhaps unexpectedly) countable locally finite groups have infinitely many.

Comment: @Derek: Thanks. So when R.E.M. sing that it's *the* end of the world as we know it, I suppose they mean that the world is not a free group, nor it is a countable locally finite group, or a finite group for that matter...

Comment: One remaining question, sorry if it comes across rather stupid, but the reason i assumed that $2E$ is multiplying each element of $E$ by $2$ is because i am used to consider $2\mathbb{Z}$ in that way, why is $2\mathbb{Z}$ a different matter?

Comment: @Zest: The reason that you know $2E$ means to add $2$ to each element of $E$ is because in the expression $gE = \{g \cdot E \mid h \in E\}$, that $\cdot$ symbol stands for the group operation, and the group operation on $\mathbb Z$ is addition.

Comment: Thank you Lee, highly appreciating your help.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the result about locally finite groups Derek mentions is using a cohomological definition of ends of groups which is equivalent to the usual def when working with infinite finitely generated groups.