# Groups with two ends: showing that either $E\Delta gE$ is finite or $(E\Delta gE)^\complement$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, geometric-group-theory, cayley-graphs

> Let $G$ be a finitely generated group with $e(G) = 2$, and let
> $\Gamma$ be a Cayley graph of $G$. There is then a finite subgraph $C$
> such that $\Gamma \setminus C$ has exactly two connected, unbounded
> components. By adding all the finite components of $\Gamma \setminus
>  C$ to $C$, we may assume that $\Gamma \setminus C$ consists of exactly
> two connected components, each of which is unbounded. Choose one of
> these two complements, and let $E \subset G$ consist of those elements
> of $G$ that correspond to the vertices in that component. Notice that
> we may apply elements of $G$ to $E$, forming subsets $$gE = \{g \cdot
>  h \mid h \in E\}.$$ Similarly we can left multiply $E^\complement$: $$gE^\complement
>  = \{g\cdot k \mid k \not\in E\}.$$

Now the lemma:

> **Lemma 11.30.** Let $G$ and $E$ be as above, and let $g \in G$. Then, because $G$ is two-ended, either $E\Delta gE$ is finite or $(E\Delta
>  gE)^\complement$ is finite.

**Note**:

1. $A\Delta B$ denotes the symmetric difference $(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$.
2. $e(G)$ denotes the number of ends of the group $G$.

I already asked a question about this lemma here: [Geometric Group Theory, Meier lemma 11.30 about a two-ended groups $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733281/geometric-group-theory-meier-lemma-11-30-about-a-two-ended-groups-g)

This time, i'd love to ask for an idea on how to prove this lemma. The reason why i'm a bit struggling on this is because i am really uncertain if i am not missing any scenario on how $gE$ could possibly look like.

If we imagine $G$ to be the group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ it's quite simple. $gE$ becomes the set of elements $\{g+h \mid h \in E\}$ which i can picture as some sort of translation.

But i can't find a way to generalize this to all possible scenarios where the group operation can be anything else.

The key observation is certainly that the group is two ended, but i haven't figured out how that implies the given claim.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Beware that you need to take the right Cayley graph for your lemma to hold: $g$ linked to $gs$ for $s$ generator, so that left action is by graph automorphisms, while the right action is by bounded displacements permutations. Note that $E\triangle Eg$ is always finite in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's write
$$\Gamma = E' \cup C \cup E
$$
where $E,E'$ are the two components of $\Gamma-C$, both unbounded.

We also have
$$\Gamma = gE \cup gC \cup gE'
$$
where $gE,gE'$ are the two components of $\Gamma - gC$, also both unbounded.

Now we need a case analysis. The group $G$ acts on the set consisting of its two ends. Thus each individual group element acts as a permutation of those two ends.

There are now two cases to consider, depending on whether or not $g$ fixes or swaps the two ends.

**Case 1:** $g$ fixes the the two ends. Thus $E$ and $gE$ represent the same end and so $E \Delta gE$ is bounded.

**Case 2:** $g$ swaps the two ends.

Thus $E$ and $gE'$ represent the same end, so $E \Delta gE'$ is bounded, and so $E \Delta gE^\complement = E \Delta (gE' \cup gC)$ is bounded.

Also $E'$ and $gE$ represent the same end, and so similarly $E^\complement \Delta gE$ is bounded.

Also $E'$ and $gE'$ represent different ends, so $E' \cap gE'$ is bounded, and so $E^\complement \cap gE^\complement = (E' \cup G) \cap (gE' \cup gC)$ is bounded.

Putting these together it follows that
$$(E \Delta gE)^\complement = (E \cap gE^\complement) \cup (E^\complement \cap gE^\complement) \cup (E^\complement \cap gE)
$$
is bounded.

Comment: beautiful, thank you Lee!

Answer (score 1):

The group is virtually cyclic and infinite. Therefore in the Cayley graph there is a line (more precisely, a quasi-geodesic)  $l$ such that the whole Cayley graph is in a $\delta$-neighborhood of $l$ for some $\delta$ This implies your statement (just as for the group of integers).

Comment: Is your proof viable for all two ended groups? Or just the group of integers?

Comment: The fact and proof are about groups where a description of 2-ended groups is known. The proof could be similar for 2-ended graphs where every vertex has finite and bounded degree.But I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am a bit concerned that this has to be proven without assuming that $G$ is virtually cyclic and infinite. It's from Meier's book and the fact that every two-ended group is virtually $\mathbb{Z}$ is proven later.

Comment: I do not know Meier's book.  What you can say is the Cayley graph is regular and of finite degree (since you know that the group is f.g.) Hence it has a bi-infinite geodesic $l$. The ends of this geodesic are the two ends of the group. You need to deduce that the whole Cayley graph is in a tubular neighborhood of $l$. I do not know how to prove that directly. You can ask Meier.